# Python3 C-libs: How do I serialize a class that depends on C .dlls for use in a bare instance?

Tags: python-3.x, serialization, pickle, dill, cloudpickle

For example:

```
// file foo
def my_func():
   print("foo!")

// file bar
class Bar:
   def __init__(self):
      pass 
   def hello():
      import foo.my_func
      my_func()

import dill
dill.dump(Bar(), open("bar.dpkl",mode='wb+'))
```

```
$: python3 -m venv foobar
$: source activate foobar/bin/activate
(foobar) $: python3
>>> import dill
>>> obj = dill.load(open("bar.dpkl",mode='rb')) # just fine
>>> obj.hello()
foo!
```

---

But, suppose I throw in a twist:

```
class Bar:
  def __init__(self):
     import numpy
```

Now,

```
>>> obj = dll.load(open("bar.dpkl",mode='rb'))
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
```

---

It appears as if the linked `C`-binaries are not bundled up in the `pickle` file.  However, if the code is genuine, native `python` code, the `pickle` file output by `dill` is essentially a dynamic archive.

Is there any way to extend this dynamic archive behavior to include the libraries like `numpy` et al.?  Or must these sort of `C` + `python`-shell libraries always be installed in the executing `python` environment?

---

Basically, I think the thing I am asking for is a pythonic version of a `jar` that can be generated straight from `python` code: is this possible? Or is a container with requisite dependencies the `jar` I am looking for?

Comment: I'm the `dill` author.  `dill` is the most aggressive serializer in that it can serialize entire modules, if warranted, as long as they are pure-python. For anything with C, you are correct that the assumption is that the C-dependency is installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution:

```
import dill
```

```
class Bar:
  def __init__(self, foo):
    self.basename = foo.name
    self.deps = deepcopy(foo.deps)
    self.foo = '-'.join([self.basename,'foo'])
    self.bar = '-'.join([self.basename,'bar'])

  def install(self):
    import pip
    pip.main(["install"] + self.deps) # this method will be deprecated soon

  def load(self):
    self.install()
    foo = dill.load(open(self.foo,'rb'))
    return foo
 
  def store_self():
    with open(self.bar + '.dpkl','wb+') as out:
      dill.dump(out,self)

  @classmethod
  def store(cls, foo):
    bar = cls(foo)
    bar.store_self()
    bar.install()
    with open(self.foo + '.dpkl','wb+') as out:
      dill.dump(out,foo)

class Foo:
  def __init__(self,name,*arg,**kwargs):
    self.name = name
    self.deps = [ "numpy" ]

  def hello():
    import numpy
    print("foo")
    ...


foo = Foo("Hello! I'm a foo!")
Bar.store(foo)
```

---

```
$: python3 -m venv venv-foo
$: source venv-foo/bin/activate
$: python3 -m pip install dill
>>> import dill
>>> bar = dill.load(open('bar.dpkl','rb'))
>>> foo = bar.load()
>>> foo.hello()
Hello! I am a foo!
```

No warranty of copy-pasteability, but the gist of it is there. Might have to tinker with it a bit to get the `Bar.dpkl` working.  It is also sensitive to `python3`'s version.

With some more work, native pickle can probably be used to store `Bar`, which can then be used to install `dill`.